# Concatenate text files, separating them with a new line

Tags: database, bash, text, concatenation, text-files

I have just over 100 text files in a directory, functioning as a simple database with each line containing one record. In total, these files add up to around 25GB. However, the records are not sorted alphabetically and there are many duplicates, so in order to alphabetise the contents of all ~100 text files using something like `sort -u`, I'm first trying to combine all of these files into a single large text file. A simple `cat` would be unsuitable because the beginnings and ends of the 100 text files do not contain new lines, which (to my understanding) would cause the last record in a file to become merged with the first record of the next file.

#### What solutions are there that would allow me to concatenate my text files  while ensuring there is a single new line character separating them?

Comment: `for i in *.txt; do echo >> $i; done; cat *.txt | sort -u > newfile` ?

Comment: You can sort multiple files by just listing their names on the `sort` command line. No need to concatenate.

Comment: @rici Will that sort their contents across each other? So that if File 1 happens to contain all entries beginning with "a", File 2 will continue with entries beginning with "b"?

Comment: The output is the sort of all input lines; it doesn't sort the files independently. IOW, it's the sort of the concatenation of the inputs except that every input file is treated as though it were correctly terminated. I believe that is exactly the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: I was completely unaware/had forgotten that `sort` could be used to create an output file from the sorted contents, I had just assumed it internally sorted the contents of input files given to it. So essentially, what you're saying is that doing `sort -u * > newfile.txt` in the directory that contains the text files would satisfy all of my criteria here?

Comment: If you want to sort all the files, yes. It might turn out to be faster to sort each one individually and then do a merge on the sorted temporaries. But then, it might not. TIAS.

Comment: Just be aware that a file that doesn't end in a newline is not a text file by the POSIX definition and so what any given version of any given text-processing tool does with a file like that is up to the tool. You'll probably be OK with most tools but if you notice any weirdness that might be your problem. What does `the beginnings of the 100 text files do not contain new lines` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple

```
sort -u *.db > uniquified # adjust glob as needed
```

should do it; `sort` will interpose newlines between files should it be necessary.

```
cat *.db | sort -u
```

is a classic [UUoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) and the glitch with files lacking trailing newlines is not the only issue.

Having said that, 25GB probably won't fit in your RAM, so `sort` will end up creating temporary files anyway. It might turn out to be faster to sort the files in four or five groups, and then merge the results. That could take better advantage of the large number of duplicates. But I'd only experiment if the simple command really takes an exorbitant amount of time.

Even so, sorting the files individually is probably even slower; usually the best bet is to max out your memory resources for each invocation of `sort`. You could, for example, use `xargs` with the `-n` option to split the filelist into groups of a couple of dozen files each. Once you have each group sorted, you could use `sort -m` to merge the sorted temporaries.

A couple of notes on how to improve sorting speed:

1. Use `LC_COLLATE=C sort` if you don't need locale-aware sorting of alphabetic data. That typically speeds sort up by a factor of three or four.
2. Avoid using RAM disks for temporary space. (On many Linux distros, `/tmp` is a RAM disk.) Since `sort` uses temporary disks when it runs out of RAM, putting the temporary in a RAMdisk is counterproductive. For the same reason, don't put your own temporary output files in `/tmp`. `/var/tmp` should be real disk; even better, if possible, use a second disk drive (not a slow USB drive, of course).
3. Avoid slugging your machine down with excessive swapping while you're doing the sort, by turning swap off:

   ```
   sudo swapoff -a
   ```

   You can turn it back on afterwards, although I personally run my machine like this all the time because it avoids diving into complete unresponsiveness under memory pressure.
4. The ideal is to adjust `-S` so that `sort` uses as much memory as you can spare, and avoid the use of internal temporaries by sorting in chunks which fit into that amount of memory. (Merging the sorted chunks is a lot faster than sorting, and it reads and writes sequentially without needing extra disk space.) You'll probably need to do some experimentation to find a good chunk size.

Comment: I decided to opt for this solution yesterday owing to the fact it was the simplest. I used `sort -u * -S 70% > finished.txt`. It ran for at least 6 hours before I left it to run overnight, and I woke up to find that it had terminated with the following error: `sort: write failed: /tmp/sortJZDIUm: No space left on device`. This is despite the fact that I have 16GB of RAM and 17GB free on the drive that /tmp is installed to. What would you recommend from this point?

Comment: Regarding the merging option described in your first paragraph, how would the syntax for that go? `sort -u **set of 20 files** > partial1.txt` and then `sort -m partial1.txt partial2.txt partial3.txt partial4.txt partial5.txt > finished.txt`? If so, assuming the first 5 commands sort the contents of the 5 partial files from a-z *internally*, wouldn't the final merge command need to re-sort their combined contents all over again? To me this option seems like it should take just as much at time as trying to sort all the files at once.

Comment: Small correction to my first comment, the actual command that I left running was: `sort -u --parallel=2 -S 70% * > finished.txt`.

Comment: @Hashim: the reason splitting into chunks and merging the results is likely to be faster is that the uniqify step is done at the end. (That's also why you ran out of temporary space.) So if you split and merge, the final merge is operating on less data. Also, merge doesn't need to sort. Sort is O(n log n); merge is O(n). But the main reason merge is faster is that it reads and writes sequential records, which is what the filesystem is optimised for.

Comment: @Hashim: The final command is `sort -mu partial?.txt`; you still need to uniqify lines between different chunks. But basically, yeah.

Comment: I have actually already started the process of running a version of the command I ran earlier, this time using `-T` to save temp files to my other drive with 400GB of space free. I decided to stick with the option of doing all files at once for now because I prefer being free to do other things throughout the day while the command runs as opposed to having to stop and start to run several iterations of it. How long would you recommend I let it run before it becomes too long and I should try the "splitting and merging" option? How long would be reasonable for something like this?

Comment: Really, it should be that fast? I'm using a very slow desktop, i3-2100 Dual Core at 3.10GHz. I've also heard of `LC_ALL=C sort`, would that be better or worse than `LC_COLLATE`?

Comment: If it doesn't complete in less than half an hour, should I try with the "split and merge" method?

Comment: @Hashim: sounds like a plan. Make your chunks the size of available memory so that sort doesn't need to create temporary files. Take into account how much memory is being used by whatever else you're using; a bit of experimentation watching `top` should give you a good handle. (And, as I said, turning swap off while you do that will protect you.)

Comment: I had planned to not use memory at all and use `-T directory` to force it to use temp files with my larger hard drive. Is this significantly slower than using memory?

Comment: @Hashim: it's slower but I don't know if it is *significantly* slower. You'll have to try and see, I'm afraid. A lot will depend on how many duplicates there really are.

Comment: I understand. I'll stick to keeping it in memory and using `LC_ALL=C` and let you know how I get on. Thanks a lot for your help so far, it's been invaluable.

Comment: @Hashim: Good luck. I put the comments into the answer so that they will persist.

Comment: Just wanted to report back that this worked like a charm. I ended up going for the "splitting and merging" method because I fancied the challenge, and I was amazed at just how fast `LC_ALL=C` made things. All five sub-files, ranging from 3-7GB, were sorted, de-duplicated and then merged in under 45 mins. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I would tell you to create that file by concatenating all input files and intercalating a new line in the middle:

```
out=newfile.txt
rm -f "$out"
for f in *.txt
do
    cat "$f" >> "$out"
    echo >> "$out"
done
```

Now you can sort it. Or remove empty lines, in case you think there could be some input file with a new line at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk.

```
$ od -t x1 file1
0000000 72 65 63 6f 72 64 31 0a 72 65 63 6f 72 64 32
0000017
$ od -t x1 file2
0000000 72 65 63 6f 72 64 31 0a 72 65 63 6f 72 64 32 0a
0000020 72 65 63 6f 72 64 33
0000027
$ awk 1 file1 file2
record1
record2
record1
record2
record3
```

`1` is awk script here, which means print all records

Answer (score 1):

`sort *` should be all you need but just in case you every do need to append newlines to file contents for processing by a subsequent tool, here's how to do that:

```
$ ls
file1  file2
$ cat file1
foo$
$ cat file2
bar$
$ cat file1 file2
foobar$

$ find . -type f -exec sh -c '(cat {}; printf "\\n")' \;
foo
bar
```

That is, of course, assuming that your `cat` can handle files that don't end in newlines!